# Оптимальный вариант отрисовки таблицы с >100 ячейками - одним объектом?

Tags: java, android, android-drawable

Создаю свою масштабируемую/скроллируемую таблицу где каждая ячейка представляет собой прямоугольник с заливкой + несколько (более 4-х) текстовых объектов (`android.graphics`).
Все это делаю программно.
Как лучше рисовать ячейку? Каждый компонент ячейки отдельно или можно ячейку или даже всю таблицу объединить в один объект типа `bitmap` или `picture`?
Попробовал объединять:
`bitmap`, как и следовало ожидать, масштабирует отвратительно.
`picture` на эмуляторах вроде работает нормально, а на моём *galaxy tab* глючит "по черному" - отрисовывает только первую ячейку да и масштабирует почему-то тоже плохо, хотя на эмуляторе норм. Махинации с `hardvare acceleration` ни к чему не привели ни в манифесте, ни программно.

По сути надо программно создать объект (как `png`, а не `bitmap`), который будет нормально масштабироваться.

Пока сделал все отдельно, все рисуется и масштабируется, вроде даже шустро работает, но... терзают смутные сомненья. Наверняка есть способ лучше.

Comment: А почему эту таблицу нужно делать в виде графического файла? Почему не использовать TableLayout, GridView и тп. виджеты

Comment: Я не смог ее такой сделать с соблюдением всех требований: Она строго определенного формата с дырками в строгоопределенных местах + с разным заполнением (одна ячейка одного цвета, другая другого) +Цвет и заполнение меняется программно. + скроллируемая по вертикали и горизонтали + масштабируемая. С canvas все это для меня как-то проще показалось.

Comment: В принципе что-то подобное у меня получилось через RelativeLayot где каждая ячейка тоже RelativeLayout. Но я не смог под своей ячейкой нарисовать прямоугольник рамки и фона. Не смог совместить layout и canvas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Через `picture` все заработало отлично. 
Все-таки я изначально ошибся с аппаратным ускорением. Отключил его в манифесте только в активити, а надо во всем приложении `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"`!